# Use value from a table in a second table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables called *users* and *packages*.

In *users* there is a column called "package" and in *packages* a column called "id".

What i'm trying to accomplish is, if the package id in the users table is changed to, lets say "1", then another field from the users table called "storage" should be changed to the corresponding "maxstorage" from the packages table... A little illustration here:

[image: Tables]

DATABASE:

[image: DB]

Let's say Joe would like to upgrade to package number 2. Then his storage amount should be changed when his package is changed. It should pull the maxstorage from the packages table into the users table and then in the column "storage"...

How can i accomplish this?

> It's pretty hard to explain for me, if anyone gets it then please edit for easier explanation.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible in a query (or at least, not simple). You have to move this logic to your code, e.g. you have a query which changes a row in the *users* table. In that query, also update storage.

Even better, drop the users.storage_id completely. Good databases don't repeat. you already have the data in the *packages* table, why copy it to the users?

```
SELECT users.name, packages.maxstorage 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN packages ON  (users.package_id = packages.id)
```

Comment: Maybe, I'm not known with FK's :) but that query should do it.

Comment: There is more things in the packages table, for example expiration time and name etc. Which is why i need it.

Comment: Then add more to your select. The 'rule'  is DRY, Dont Repeat Yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It can be that I didn't understand correctly your question, but what about this:
(pls make appropriate considerations on transactions to avoid conflicts).

```
CREATE TABLE P (ID INT, MAXSTORAGE INT);
CREATE TABLE U (USR_ID INT, PACKAGE_ID INT, STORAGE INT);

CREATE TRIGGER U_STORAGE_UPDATE BEFORE UPDATE ON U
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.STORAGE = IF(NEW.PACKAGE_ID<>OLD.PACKAGE_ID , (SELECT MAXSTORAGE FROM P WHERE ID = NEW.PACKAGE_ID), NEW.STORAGE);
  END;

INSERT INTO P VALUES (1,12345);
INSERT INTO P VALUES (2,54321);

INSERT INTO U VALUES (1,1,12000);
INSERT INTO U VALUES (2,2,60000);

SELECT * FROM U;

UPDATE U SET PACKAGE_ID=2  WHERE USR_ID=1;

SELECT * FROM U;

UPDATE U SET STORAGE=23  
WHERE USR_ID=1;

SELECT * FROM U;

DROP TABLE P;
DROP TABLE U;
```

Output:
  ante

```
    USR_ID  PACKAGE_ID  STORAGE
1   1   1   12000
2   2   2   60000
```

post 1st update

```
    USR_ID  PACKAGE_ID  STORAGE
1   1   2   54321
2   2   2   60000
```

post 2nd update

```
USR_ID  PACKAGE_ID  STORAGE
1   1   2   23
2   2   2   60000
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't answer the question but might be useful to you:

The 'package' column in Users should have a foreign key restraint on 'id' in Packages. This ensures that all data in the 'package' column corresponds to a valid value in the Packages table. Otherwise you could enter some data into the 'package' column that doesn't have a value in the Packages table.